# Can a linq to objects SelectMany selector result in nothing added to the collection?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use SelectMany to compile a list of lists, however the selector may encounter an error and therefore have no results.

I'm going to provide the actual function I'm trying to write and then the snippet I wrote to further explore it.

In the production code, my goal is to handle the case that the serializer throws an exception.

In the sample code I have solved the problem for the case of strings, but am not sure if this solution is really more than a hack.

**Production Code:**

```
public List<click> Clicks(int advertiserId, DateTime date)
{
    var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(DirName(date, advertiserId));
    if (dirInfo.Exists)
    {
        var files = dirInfo.EnumerateFiles();
        var clicks = files.SelectMany(c =>
            {
                using (var stream = c.OpenRead())
                {
                    return (click[])clicksSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
                }              
            });
        return clicks.ToList();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Sample Code:**

```
void Main()
{
    var ids = new [] { 1, 2, 3 };
    var names = ids.SelectMany(id =>
        {
            try
            {
                return GetNames(id);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Error getting names for {0}", id);

                // RESULT: NullReferenceException at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()
                //return null;

                // RESULT: an empty string in the result, but how to this with other types?
                return new string [] { string.Empty };
            }
        });
    foreach (var name in names)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Name: {0}", name);
    }
}

string[] GetNames(int id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case 1:
            return new [] {"Jim", "Bob"};
        case 2:
            return new [] {"Harry", "Larry"};
        default:
            throw new Exception("invalid id");
    }
}
```

Comment: What would the element be for an arbitrary type `T`? You could return `default(T)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return `default(T)` for some other type `T` although I'm not sure how useful that would be:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TrySelectMany<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
{
    return seq.SelectMany(i => {
        try {
            return selector(i);
        }
        catch(Exception) {
            return new T[] { default(T) };
        }
    });
}
```

I would consider returning `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` instead in the catch block.

Comment: I flipped a coin on which answer to pick.. both helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, returning an empty sequence is entirely valid, although I'd use

```
return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
```

instead to be clearer.

`SelectMany` - in the form you've used - really does just flatten a sequence of sequences, and if some of those intermediate sequences are empty, they'll just contribute nothing to the overall sequence. No problem in that at all.